# Finding remaining months in a fiscal year

Tags: ruby

I need to calculate the number of remaining months in a fiscal year from the given month, where a fiscal year starts from the fourth month of the year. I have an array illustrating this:

```
months = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```

Some expected inputs and outputs are:

- `4` => `11`
- `10` => `5`
- `2` => `1`

However, when `3` is given (as well as when `2` is given), I want it to return `1` because the return value is used in a multiplication, and if it is 0, the output becomes `0`.

I solved this by doing:

```
@month == 3 ?
annual_taxable_income += total_monthly_income_present_month :
annual_taxable_income += total_monthly_income_present_month + @basic_salary * fiscal_months_array[@month - 3, 12].size
```

I used ternary operator to check if there is `3`, and if there is, then do not find the remaining months. The solution is working but I need a better way to do this.

Comment: You need to reconsider your calculation that comes after this. Why does `3` have to be exceptional? Is there a way to avoid it? If it really should be handled as an exceptional case, then it should be handled as exceptional in the routine shown here as well.

Comment: _"value is used in a multiplication, and if it is 0, the output becomes 0"_ – only the result of the multiplication becomes 0, so you'd have `total_monthly_income_present_month + 0`. Not sure why you need the ternary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def remaining_months(mon)
  (3 - mon) % 12
end

(1..12).each { |mon| puts "#{mon} -> #{remaining_months(mon)}" }
1  ->  2
2  ->  1
3  ->  0
4  -> 11
5  -> 10
6  ->  9
7  ->  8
8  ->  7
9  ->  6
10 ->  5
11 ->  4
12 ->  3
```

You therefore would want `[remaining_months(mon), 1].max`. It's best not to put this part in the method `remaining_months`.

Note that the array `months` is determined by the first element, which is the first month of the fiscal year (`4`). It therefore should not be surprising that only the first element is needed in calculations.

Do you ever have problems like this where a modulus is involved and finding yourself trying different expressions until you finally find hit on one that works? Here's a way to do that for those in audience who are somewhat lazy by nature.

```
RESULT = [*(3..11), 0, 1, 2].reverse

a = [*(-12..0), *(1..12)]

a.product([1,-1], (a-[0]), a).
  select do |c1,c2,c3,c4|
    (1..12).all? { |mon| c1 + c2 * ((c3 * mon + c4) % 12) == RESULT[mon-1] }
  end.
  map do |c1,c2,c3,c4|
    s1 = c1.zero? ? '' : c1.to_s 
    s2 = case c1.zero?
         when true then c2==1 ? '' : '-'
         else c2==1 ? ' + ' : ' - '
         end
    s3 = if c3 > 0
           c3==1 ? '' : "#{c3} * "
         else
           c3==-1 ? '- ' : "- #{c3.abs} * "
         end
    s4 = case c4 <=> 0
         when 0 then ''
         when -1 then " - #{c4.abs}"
         else " + #{c4}"
         end
    "#{s1}#{s2}((#{s3}mon#{s4}) % 12"
  end
  #=> ["((- mon - 9) % 12",
  #    "((- mon + 3) % 12",
  #    "(11 * mon - 9) % 12",
  #    "(11 * mon + 3) % 12",
  #    "11 - ((- 11 * mon - 4) % 12",
  #    "11 - ((- 11 * mon + 8) % 12",
  #    "11 - ((mon - 4) % 12",
  #    "11 - ((mon + 8) % 12"]
```

Take your pick!

Here we obtain the following intermediate result.

```
a.product([1,-1], (a-[0]), a).
  select do |c1,c2,c3,c4|
    (1..12).all? { |mon| c1 + c2 * ((c3 * mon + c4) % 12) == RESULT[mon-1] }
  end
  #=> [[0, 1, -1, -9], [0, 1, -1, 3], [0, 1, 11, -9], [0, 1, 11, 3],
  #    [11, -1, -11, -4], [11, -1, -11, 8], [11, -1, 1, -4], [11, -1, 1, 8]]
```

Comment: Your code gives me `12` for an input of `3`. To get zero, I had to add parentheses: `(12 - (mon + 9)) % 12`, which is equivalent to `(3 - mon) % 12`.

Comment: @showaltb, after reviewing my IRB session I see I transposed the wrong code to my answer. The operative line of the method that produced those results was `11 - (mon + 8) % 12`, but `(3 - mon) % 12` is simpler and therefore preferable. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could set the min value of the starting index value with max

```
fiscal_months = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3]
index = [@month-3, 1].max
annual_taxable_income += total_monthly_income_present_month + @basic_salary * fiscal_months[index, 12].size
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you want a function that returns the same answer (1) for two different inputs (2,3).  But, if that is the case you could do it like this.  It is brute force but makes clear what you are trying to do:

```
def num_remaining_months_for (m)
  fiscal_months = [4,  5,  6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
  remaining =     [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6,  5,  4, 3 , 2, 1, 1]
  index = fiscal_months.index(m)
  remaining[index]
end

(1..12).each do |e|
  puts "For month #{e} => #{num_remaining_months_for(e)} remaining"
end
```

The results are:

```
For month 1 => 2 remaining
For month 2 => 1 remaining
For month 3 => 1 remaining
For month 4 => 11 remaining
For month 5 => 10 remaining
For month 6 => 9 remaining
For month 7 => 8 remaining
For month 8 => 7 remaining
For month 9 => 6 remaining
For month 10 => 5 remaining
For month 11 => 4 remaining
For month 12 => 3 remaining
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that. I think it's clearer.

```
def number_of_remaining_months(month)
  fiscal_months_array = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
  month = 2 if month == 3
  fiscal_months_array.count - 1 - fiscal_months_array.index(month)
end

puts("Number of the month [1-12]:")
month = Integer(gets.chomp)
result = number_of_remaining_months(month)
annual_taxable_income = total_monthly_income_present_month +
                        @basic_salary * result
```

I hope it useful for you.